# Upgrading doesn't update VirtualStore file

Tags: wix

I haven an installer which must run with elevated admin rights if UAC is enabled.  This works fine.  When I upgrade the app (using the MajorUpgrade element) the app gets uninstalled and reinstalled correcly.

During runtime the app attempts to change some files in the program files folder which places copies them items in the users virtualstore.  These do not get removed during uninstall.

During the upgrade/reinstall process, is there a correct way to delete the application file copies, for all users, in the VirtualStore?

Answer (score 0):

Files placed into a virtual store are, by definition of who wrote them and when, per-user data files. Such files typically should not be removed during uninstallation. If the files in question are not actually per-user data files, the application that caused them to be written should be fixed to write to a proper location, update them in a controlled fashion, or even not write them at all.

Comment: Currently the file (not user data) gets placed in the VirtualStore by the OS when the app accesses it.  It's attempting to make a slight modification to file. We're working on fixing this beacuse that is not the correct function.